implementing native admob sdk banner in progressive framework quasar using capacitor
Im using quasar framework and capacitor to build app, im planning to integrat ethe admob sdk native since im the capacitor-community/admob doesnt provide awhy to control the banner style like bind it in an element i try the native way.
this is the MainActivity.java
    package com.example.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient; // Import this
import com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {
    private AdView adView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set up the WebView first
        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/public/index.html");

        // Initialize AdMob
        MobileAds.initialize(this, initializationStatus -> {});

        // Load the AdView
        adView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}

the activity_main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- WebView for displaying your web content -->
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <!-- AdView for displaying the AdMob banner ad -->
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:adSize="BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"/>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

the issue with this code is that this shows the login page, but it interrupts the routing like I can't access different page anymore even if I login it doesn't let me login.
but the banner ad shows my only problem the WebView shows only the login page and can't move from that no matter what I do.
but if I remove that everything works perfectly but I can't implement the banner using native way.
just for reference this is the default
package com.example.app;

import com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity;

public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {}

separate..--
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


any suggestion sensei..
